# Permission denied to connect with table only privileges set

Tags: mysql

- MySQL 5.1.41 community (Windows Server 2003)
- .Net/Connector 6.1.3.0

I've just created a new user and rather than grant schema privileges I've granted rights on only specific tables.  In other words, there are NO global or schema level permissions set, only permissions set are for a couple specific tables.  This seemed like a perfectly acceptable policy and from what I've ready MySQL will search:

1. global
2. schema/DB
3. Table
4. Column

for appropriate permissions.  However when I try to open a connection to the server using this new user account I receive a permission denied error.

> Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'%' to database 'xxxxxxx'

If I grant SELECT on the schema in question I can connect just fine.  Am I misunderstanding the way the permission system works or should it work like I think?

Comment: Notes: "privies" is not exactly a dba term. [privies](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/privies).

Comment: Some tools may execute additional queries on opening connections and this may cause the error. Try to connect with mysql command line client.

Comment: belongs on http://www.serverfault.com Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

Comment: Devart, I checked the query log and I only see a single Connect event logged:
"110816 10:23:15  543 Connect xxxxxx@192.168.1.xxx on xxxxxxxx
    543 Init DB Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'%' to database 'xxxxxxx'"

Comment: Mchl, why does my question not belong here?

Comment: Mat, Thanks for the correction, my bad

Comment: Devart, to be thorough, I tried connecting with the command line client:

"mysql --user=xxxxx --password=xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'%' to database 'xxxxxxxxx'"

Comment: BTW, I followed Mchl's suggestion and also posted on serverfault.com 
http://serverfault.com/questions/301760/permission-denied-on-connect-with-table-only-privileges-set